# Migrating content to SharePoint online 2013 - best practices?

Tags: c#, sql, migration, sharepoint-2013

Hi Im trying to migrate content to SharePoint Online 2013 from another source system.

What is the best tool to migrate content to SharePoint Online and why would you propose?

please note we are not talking about back up or archiving.

Trying to achieve content migration at site/list and item level for individual sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ideal version is to use a third party migration tool (e.g. by Dell or Sharegate). If you don't want to use those and your site is small enough, you can migrate individual lists and document libraries:

1. Go to Library settings -> Save Document Library as Template
2. It will give you an option to include content. Click Ok
3. On the next page there will be a link to list template gallery
4. Select your template and click Download a Copy
5. Navigate to your destination site -> open list template gallery -> Upload Document
6. Upload your saved template
7. Now you can go to site content -> Add an App -> select the template you just uploaded and create a new doc library using it

It's not the best and fastest way, but if you want to do it for free and you have just a few libraries/lists to migrate, it might work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Kate, Yes I have used ShareGate and it answers all my questions.